# How do I refactor this bulky set of if statements?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, refactoring, dry

I have the following code that works, but I would like it to be more DRY and elegant. It feels ugly with lots of code smells.

Ideally I don't want to use CASE statements because that doesn't feel quite ruby-ish either.

```
if @property_status.eql? :rent
  if @property_type.eql? :residential
    @results = @search.results.for_rent.residential.order("#{ @sort_by } #{ @sort_order }").all.paginate(page: @page, per_page: @per_page)
  elsif @property_type.eql? :commercial
    @results = @search.results.for_rent.commercial.order("#{ @sort_by } #{ @sort_order }").all.paginate(page: @page, per_page: @per_page)
  else
    @results = @search.results.for_rent.order("#{ @sort_by } #{ @sort_order }").all.paginate(page: @page, per_page: @per_page)
  end
elsif @property_status.eql? :sale
  if @property_type.eql? :residential
    @results = @search.results.for_sale.residential.order("#{ @sort_by } #{ @sort_order }").all.paginate(page: @page, per_page: @per_page)
  elsif @property_type.eql? :commercial
    @results = @search.results.for_sale.commercial.order("#{ @sort_by } #{ @sort_order }").all.paginate(page: @page, per_page: @per_page)
  else
    @results = @search.results.for_sale.order("#{ @sort_by } #{ @sort_order }").all.paginate(page: @page, per_page: @per_page)
  end
else
  @results = @search.results.order("#{ @sort_by } #{ @sort_order }").all.paginate(page: @page, per_page: @per_page)
end
```

Thoughts?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be better suited for [codereview.se].

Answer (score 4):

First recognize that this:

```
@results = @search.results.for_rent.residential.order("#{ @sort_by } #{ @sort_order }").all.paginate(page: @page, per_page: @per_page)
```

is equivalent to:

```
@results = @search.results
@results = @results.for_rent
@results = @results.residential
@results = @results.order(@sort_by => @sort_order).paginate(page: @page, per_page: @per_page)
```

Assuming that `@sort_by` and `@sort_order` are always set of course. The important thing is that you can build the query piece by piece and choose which pieces to add depending on your instance variables. You could add a couple simple helpers:

```
def add_property_status_to(query)
  case @property_status
  when :rent, :sale
    query.public_send("for_#{@property_type}")
  else
    query
  end
end

def add_property_type_to(query)
  case @property_type
  when :residential, :commercial
    query.public_send(@property_type)
  else
    query
  end
end
```

and then say things like this:

```
query = @search.results
query = add_property_status_to(query)
query = add_property_type_to(query)

@results = query.order(@sort_by => @sort_order).paginate(page: @page, per_page: @per_page)
```

You can think of the `add_property_status_to` and `add_property_type_to` methods as local single use scopes. If you need to use them in multiple places then you could make them class methods on whatever `@search.results` is and say things like:

```
query = @search.results
query = query.with_property_status(@property_status)
query = query.with_property_type(@property_type)

@results = query.order(@sort_by => @sort_order).paginate(page: @page, per_page: @per_page)
```

Answer (score 2):

I didn't test it but I think something along the lines of:

```
def results
  return results_for_rent if for_rent?
  return results_for_sale if for_sale?
  default_results
end

def for_rent?
  @property_status.eql? :rent
end

def for_sale?
  @property_status.eql? :sale
end

def default_results
  @results = @search.results.order("#{ @sort_by } #{ @sort_order 
   }").all.paginate(page: @page, per_page: @per_page)
end

def results_for_rent
  if [:residential, :commercial].includes?(@property_type)
    results(@property_type, type: :for_rent)
    return 
  end
  @results = @search.results.for_rent.commercial.order("#{ @sort_by } #{ 
  @sort_order }").all.paginate(page: @page, per_page: @per_page)
end

def results_for_sale
  if [:residential, :commercial].includes?(@property_type)
    results(kind, type: :for_sale)
    return
  end
  @results = @search.results.for_sale.order("#{ @sort_by } #{ @sort_order 
  }").all.paginate(page: @page, per_page: @per_page)
end

def results(kind:, type: )
  @results = @search.results.send(kind).send(type).order("#{ @sort_by } #{ 
  @sort_order }").all.paginate(page: @page, per_page: @per_page)
end
```

You can also refactor the .all.pagination part which is the same, but you get the idea. You can also refactor `results_for_rent` and `results_for_sale` methods by adding one argument

Comment: Thanks for this, although this feels like it is more unreadable and harder to follow than the original. So I feel like I sacrifice understandability for semi-DRYness.

Comment: it is easier to follow, because: `results` methods has only 3 conditionals.

Comment: Note that Rails add `Object#in?` so you can say things like `@property_type.in?(%i[residential commercial])`, often reads easier than the equivalent `#include?` version.